# How to set colour in child Clistbox with owner CMFCTabCtrl Class

Tags: c++, mfc

I using MFC AppWizard and created the SDI application 
I need to set colour for the outputwnd debug tab in some sequence 
for example 
if any wrong value entered in the some control
 i need to display text in RED stating that invalid value entered

if login done welcome message in GREEN and so on

I tried to use DrawItem 
I am not able to set the listBox stye as LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED|LBS_HASSTRING
on AddString i am getting error

How to set colour in child Clistbox with owner CMFCTabCtrl Class

Comment: Be aware of how this might look if someone's desktop is configured to use colors different from the default. Some combinations can become completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override `CListBox::DrawItem`. There's an example in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc9hahtd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

few years ago i use this advanced mvc listbox from Ultimate Toolbox
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox_ListBoxEx.aspx

You can easy change items color, font etc with this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for quick and helpfull reply 
The help resolved my problem and I am able to change the colour and font of the list box 
One more thing i want to add 
We need to override measureItem as well. No need to add any code but need to have defination and declaration 
otherwise the application will throw execption for using LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED|LBS_HASSTRING